# How to add string at the beginning of each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a string at the beginning of each row- either positive or negative - depending on the value in the columns:
[image]

I keep getting ValueError, as per screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for prefixes by conditions and add to index:

```
df.index = df['positive'].eq(1).map({True:'positive_', False:'negative_'}) + df.index
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.index = np.where(df['positive'].eq(1), 'positive_','negative_') + df.index
```

Answer (score 2):

For a generic method to handle any number of columns, use [`pandas.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies):

```
cols = ['positive', 'negative']

user_input_1.index = (pd.from_dummies(user_input_1[cols]).squeeze()
                      +'_'+user_input_1.index
                      )
```

Example input:

```
   Score  positive  negative
A      1         1         0
B      2         0         1
C      3         1         0
```

Output:

```
            Score  positive  negative
positive_A      1         1         0
negative_B      2         0         1
positive_C      3         1         0
```